# Stack Overflow error in flutter utilizing provider package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

When using "provider" package for state management in flutter I received the following stack overflow error. Here I am using the ChangeNotifierProvider in main.dart file. What is the reason for this error and how to get rid of this?

```
I/flutter ( 7382): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7382): The following StackOverflowError was thrown building ProductGrid(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter ( 7382): [InheritedProvider<Products>]):
I/flutter ( 7382): Stack Overflow
I/flutter ( 7382): 
I/flutter ( 7382): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 7382): #0      new _GrowableList (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:93:3)
I/flutter ( 7382): #1      new List._fromLiteral (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:71:18)
I/flutter ( 7382): #2      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart)
I/flutter ( 7382): #3      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #4      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #5      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #6      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #7      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #8      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
I/flutter ( 7382): #9      Products.items (package:meal_shop/providers/products.dart:42:17)
```

This is my main.dart where I am using ChangeNotifierProvider.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/product_overview_screen.dart';
import './screens/product_detail_screen.dart';
import './providers/products.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (ctx)=>Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
        fontFamily: 'Lato'
      ),
      home:ProductOverviewScreen(),
      routes:{
        ProductDetailScreen.routeName:(ctx)=>ProductDetailScreen(),
      } ,
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show the code of your ProductGrid and how Products class works